# iOS Enterprise App Distribution – Provisioning Profile expired

Tags: ios, date, provisioning-profile

How I can check in App when expired Provisioning Profile and notify user about date?

[Example](http://www.duskbeforethedawn.net/2014/06/what-time-does-an-apple-provisioning-profile-expire/)

I have found here. But this file is not included in a bundle of the project. Maybe there are some options? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite this being a MAC OS X prov checker, it applies all the same to iOS too:

https://github.com/LigeiaRowena/ProvisioningInfo

Personally, that information shouldn't bother your users. You should have a clear record of when they expire, and notify the users via push notifications and/or some form of REST api for expiration dates.

Ideally, the best way to handle this is to periodically (at least once a year) push out an update with nothing more than a new embedded mprov.

Do you specifically need your users to notify you as to when your provisioning profiles are expiring?

But in terms of reading the plist file:

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"path/to/file.plist"]
```

This also seems to be a previously answered question at:

[Get the EXPIRATION date of a Provisioning Profile at Run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961267/get-the-expiration-date-of-a-provisioning-profile-at-run-time)

but to reiterate the code:

```
- (NSString*) getExpiry{

    NSString *profilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"embedded" ofType:@"mobileprovision"];
    // Check provisioning profile existence
    if (profilePath)
    {
        // Get hex representation
        NSData *profileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:profilePath];
        NSString *profileString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", profileData];

        // Remove brackets at beginning and end
        profileString = [profileString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:@""];
        profileString = [profileString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(profileString.length - 1, 1) withString:@""];

        // Remove spaces
        profileString = [profileString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];


        // Convert hex values to readable characters
        NSMutableString *profileText = [NSMutableString new];
        for (int i = 0; i < profileString.length; i += 2)
        {
            NSString *hexChar = [profileString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 2)];
            int value = 0;
            sscanf([hexChar cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], "%x", &value);
            [profileText appendFormat:@"%c", (char)value];
        }

        // Remove whitespaces and new lines characters
        NSArray *profileWords = [profileText componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

        //There must be a better word to search through this as a structure! Need 'date' sibling to <key>ExpirationDate</key>, or use regex
        BOOL sibling = false;
        for (NSString* word in profileWords){
            if ([word isEqualToString:@"<key>ExpirationDate</key>"]){
                NSLog(@"Got to the key, now need the date!");
                sibling = true;
            }
            if (sibling && ([word rangeOfString:@"<date>"].location != NSNotFound)) {
                NSLog(@"Found it, you win!");
                NSLog(@"Expires: %@",word);
                return word;
            }
        }

    }

    return @"";
}
```