# Getting the path of the Provisioning profile in xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am developing apps using the enterprise certificate. I am facing the problem that when the provisioning profile expires the app doe not work. I want a mechanism where in the app informs the users to get the app signed again. My method is to get the expiration date from the provisioning profile in the application using the following code and then comparing that with the date. This can be compared with date and then popup can be shown to inform the user. 
I am using the following code a the following link to get the date  [Get the EXPIRATION date of a Provisioning Profile at Run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961267/get-the-expiration-date-of-a-provisioning-profile-at-run-time)
. This is in objective c code. I am trying to convert this in chsarp and  get the embedded.mobileprovision. But I am getting null value in the "profilePath".

```
   string profilePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("embedded", "mobileprovision");
```

MY QUESTION:
How can I get the path and then check the provisioning profile date in Xamarin ?

Comment: Sorry, but it seems to me that you don't get what a provisioning profile does. You don't want to bother the end-user with this do you? It is you as the developer who has to make sure you have a new profile etc. Also your app still works after the profile has expired. You (as a developer) can't update it, but the version thats in the store will keep on working.

Comment: I want to tell the user that the profile is about to get expired in upcoming 30 days (for example) and tell him to get it re-signed. This is an enterprise app.

Comment: Still don't think the end-user should be bothered with this. Just let someone who can actually do something about this add a reminder to their calendar. But anyways, check [this link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/) for in-depth information about the iOS filesystem in Xamarin