# My app stopped opening

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

i have a free account not a paid dev one
 i have not  updated my app recently and i was wondering if this is what could have caused it

i check my provisioning profile and it says the newest licence was created TODAY , i didn't run the app thought Xcode today, but if i do, i know it will be all ok, i just want to know why did my app stop working, is there a way i can check for memory leaks etc or could it simply be that the licence doesn't update online but only when running the app  thought Xcode (so you get 7 days )

Comment: I think it's because with free accounts, apps have very limited lifespan started from Xcode. Relaunch it from Xcode. For instance, in TestFlight, they have currently a 90 days lifespan before "crashing" at launch.?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the device console to see if the app is "crashing" due to an expired / invalid provisioning profile.  For information around seeing that information in the console, you can get that information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30992454/3708242).

If you want to build in provisioning profile checking into your app to see when the app provisioning profile is set to expire within the app itself (or the certificate used to sign the app), you can see that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49261676/3708242). Accessing the profile information at runtime is challenging, but can be done.

However, if you just want to confirm that the app is crashing at launch due to the profile, simply check the device console.

Also, free account provisioning profiles will last only 7 days.  So you have a week to run the app. But if you build the app when you provisioning profile is 3 days old, that only gives you 4 days from when you build the app to a device.

Also, the having a new provisioning profile in Xcode has no effect on the device.  When you run on the device from Xcode (or install an .ipa from a web link), iOS installed the profile on the device.  If you don't run from Xcode, your devices provisioning profile will be older than the one in Xcode and the app will not run.