# What affect does the iOS Development Certificate Expiry have on Distribution Provisioning Profile?

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile

What affect does the iOS Development Certificate Expiry have on Distribution Provisioning Profile? We have recently updated our distribution profile for another year and will be releasing our enterprise app soon.  Our Developer Certificate is set to expire in 30 days.

We won't need to resign our enterprise app after generating a new Developer Certificate.  **Right?**  My google research makes me think that we won't, but I can't find anything that explicitly states if this is the case.  I really need to be sure that our users use of the app will go un-interrupted.  Any advice or resources you can provide regarding the matter will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, I believe you have an enterprise app that you are distributing to people that was signed using an In House Distribution Profile / Certificate.  Your iOS Developer certificate is about to expire soon.

Since your distributed app is being signed with the distribution signing identity (cert and profile), your development certificate is not in play at all and **will have no effect on your distributed app**.

Please make sure that you are in fact, signing the distributed app with the distribution signing identity, though.

You can actually do some certificate / profile checks at runtime with the code found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49261676/3708242

Comment: Thanks @wottle.  You are right it is an enterprise app.