# List all the Provisional Profiles on the device at Runtime and get their EXPIRY dates

Tags: ios, swift, provisioning-profile, provisioning, ios-provisioning

My Enterprise app is being distributed with a Provisioning profile (oldPP) that expires in 3 months. I have created a new provisioning profile (newPP), placed it on a device which has my app already installed. Now there are 2 profiles, I can see them when I hook up the device with the App Configurator 2 tool.

Using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961267/get-the-expiration-date-of-a-provisioning-profile-at-run-time/) i was able to get the expiry date of the embedded provisional profile (oldPP)

I also tried

`let urls = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "mobileprovision", subdirectory: nil)`

But this only returns url of (oldPP) which is in my main app bundle.
Where is (newPP) located? I just cannot figure it out.

My goal eventually is to notify the user after opening the app with a message if the latest profile is expiring. For this I need to read the expiry dates on both (oldPP) and (newPP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to access the other provisioning profiles installed on the device because of iOS sandboxing.  You will only get the oldPP because that is the only .mobileprovision file in the applications bundle.  I do not believe Apple will ever let apps query for PPs on the device, as this could be used to get information about other apps installed on the device.

I would recommend simply repackaging your enterprise app each time the PP is expiring, so that the embedded.mobileprovision file is always the latest.  Then you can use the notification feature (I have a way to get the pp expiration as well as the certificate expiration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49188337/get-details-of-provisioning-profile-and-certificate-at-runtime/49261676#49261676)) to inform the user that they need to install a new version of the app.  Even if there are no code changes, the ipa will at least have the bew embedded.mobileprovision file in it.

And if you use MDM, rather than pushing the new provisioning profile to the device, you can now push the new ipa, with new embedded.mobileprovision file to the devices.  If you are asking them to update their provisioning profile, it's probably just as simple to provide them a link to the .ipa file.

Unfortunately, it's unlikely that Apple will allow developers toquery other PPs installed on the iOS device.